# Change Microsoft Graph Resource for Sharepoint Webhook

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, webhooks

I am currently working out the Microsoft Graph tutorial with C# .Net Core, and in the process I came across the following C#-method for Subscription:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Get()
{
  var graphServiceClient = GetGraphClient();

  var sub = new Microsoft.Graph.Subscription();
  sub.ChangeType = "updated";
  sub.NotificationUrl = config.Ngrok + "/api/notifications";
  sub.Resource = "/users";
  sub.ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15);
  sub.ClientState = "SecretClientState";

  var newSubscription = await graphServiceClient
    .Subscriptions
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(sub);

  Subscriptions[newSubscription.Id] = newSubscription;

  if (subscriptionTimer == null)
  {
    subscriptionTimer = new Timer(CheckSubscriptions, null, 5000, 15000);
  }

  return $"Subscribed. Id: {newSubscription.Id}, Expiration: {newSubscription.ExpirationDateTime}";
}
```

and wanted to know how I can change it for sharepoint lists instead of users.

If I change it to /sites/{site-id} or similar it does not work. (see sub.Resource)

Github-Link: [MS Repo](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-changenotifications/blob/master/demos/03-track-changes/Controllers/NotificationsController.cs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself with the sub.Resource: /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Graph API uses a webhook mechanism to deliver change notifications to clients. Using the Microsoft Graph API, an app can subscribe to changes for list under a SharePoint site.

Resource Path - Changes to content within the list:
/sites/{id}/lists/{id}

For details round how to subscribe to and handle incoming notifications, see [Set up notifications for changes in user data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-with-resource-data)

Also make sure you check necessary [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0) needed here.